# Customizing the presentTextInputController and voice dictation scene controllers?

Tags: swift, watchkit

presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions method gives us

[image]

Can we access this scene to customize the UI with different emoji/microphone buttons? We can only change the array of suggestions?

When the microphone is clicked to dictate a reply we get this very simple scene. Is there a controller for this or is it a private Apple controller that's called?

[image]

Do we have to use this very plain waveform or can we use our own custom waveform like these? I have a custom subclass animated waveform I'd like to use.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions:allowedInputMode:completion:), currently you can only customize the suggestion text, whether or not the emoji's/animated emoji's are available, and if the suggestion text should be shown at all.

Comment: I saw that but when the microphone icon is pressed it presents a voice dictation scene. The voice dictation scene must be separate controller. Lots of apps have seem to have a custom voice dictation HUD. Like the WorkFlow app  screenshot here. iTunes: http://www.bit.ly/1WyN7ZG  So if this isn't a part of `presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions` what API is this?

Comment: So if it's not allowed, why does the Microsoft Translator here have a custom voice waveform? It seems to be using Apple's waveform. At the 1:23 mark. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B1YygEPF5vI  Normally it's just the boring white flat line.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't use the built in Siri text to speech. In watchOS 2 you have direct access to the microphone, so they use their own text to speech software and thus can display any UI that they want.

Comment: Ok then so this is what I was asking. If my chat app #1 is using its own text to speech engine and #2 has a reply button in the conversation, I can use whatever voice dictation waveform HUD I want? How is MS allowed to use the identical waveform HUD that Siri has? Is this not copyright?  Can 3rd party text-to-speech engines be just as good as Apple's? If you edit your answer so it's more voice waveform related I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Since its an app for watchOS, I don't think there is any copyright issues there. 3rd party speech-to-text engines are unlikely to be as good as Apple's, but some exist you could look into using. Luckily for Microsoft they have their own speech to text engine that is comparable to Apple's (they have been doing speech to text for a long time) that they include in their Cortona product. I don't think it is realistic to try to implement this in your own watch app without causing major extra work on your part.

Comment: Yes of course. So basically we can only implement our own audio waveform element if we are using our own speech engine.  I marked your answer as correct because you answered a lot of questions. I think we should paste everything as a single answer. Up to you. Cheers.